# How to create a nested array from collection with parent IDs in laravel?

Tags: laravel

> I want to create a nested array which maintain parent child relations
> by using their parent_id.I want to make the following query results
> into nested array.NB:I have used same table to keep all category data.

```
$catItems= ProductCategory::all()->toArray();
        $source = array();
        foreach($catItems as $key => $value) {
            $source[$key] = $value;
        }
```

> the following method I applied to create nested array

```
$nested = array();
     
        foreach ($source as &$s) {
            if(is_null($s['parent_id']) ) {
                // no parent_id so we put it in the root of the array
                $nested[] = &$s;
            }
            else {
                $pid = $s['parent_id'];
                if ( isset($source[$pid])) {
                    // If the parent ID exists in the source array
                    // we add it to the 'children' array of the parent after initializing it.
     
                    if ( !isset($source[$pid]['children']) ) {
                        $source[$pid]['children'] = array();
                    }
                    $source[$pid]['children'][] = &$s;
                }
            }
        }
```

> If i do dd($source) i am getting the following output

```
 array:3 [▼
      0 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "name" => "Electronics"
        "status" => 1
        "parent_id" => null
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-05-06T06:32:37.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-06T06:32:37.000000Z"
      ]
      1 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 6
        "name" => "tv"
        "status" => 1
        "parent_id" => 5
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-05-06T06:33:00.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-06T06:33:00.000000Z"
      ]
      2 => array:8 [▼
        "id" => 7
        "name" => "Home appliances"
        "status" => 1
        "parent_id" => null
        "created_by" => 1
        "updated_by" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-05-06T06:33:16.000000Z"
        "updated_at" => "2021-05-06T06:33:16.000000Z"
      ]
    ]
```

> If i do dd($nested) i am getting the only parent array like bellow :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => & array:8 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "name" => "Electronics"
    "status" => 1
    "parent_id" => null
    "created_by" => 1
    "updated_by" => null
    "created_at" => "2021-05-06T06:32:37.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-06T06:32:37.000000Z"
  ]
  1 => & array:8 [▼
    "id" => 7
    "name" => "Home appliances"
    "status" => 1
    "parent_id" => null
    "created_by" => 1
    "updated_by" => null
    "created_at" => "2021-05-06T06:33:16.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2021-05-06T06:33:16.000000Z"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create this function to access children in ProductCategory.php file:

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductCategory::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

In your controller:

```
$cartItems = ProductCategory::with('children')->get();
```

If you want to get parent of any child category:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

You can get its parents like this

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class)->with('parent');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have forgotten to mention that I have only one table.

Comment: I know this code is for one table only. Try it